# c# - can convert from C# type to System.Type but not vice-versa

Tags: c#, generics

I can create a generic class that takes, as its template parameter, a C# type, and then within the generic class use the System.Type information corresponding to that C# type:

```
public class Generic<T>
{
    public bool IsArray()
    {
        return typeof(T).IsArray();
    }
    public T Create()
    {
        return blah();
    }
}
Generic<int> gi = new Generic<int>();
Debug.WriteLine("int isarray=" + gi.IsArray());
Generic<DateTime> gdt;
```

But now let's say what I have, is a System.Type.  I can't use this to instantiate my generic class:

```
FieldInfo field = foo();
Generic<field.FieldType> g;   // Not valid!
```

Is there some clever C# thing I can do, to convert a System.Type back to the original C# type?  Or some other way, to create a generic that can (1) give me information about the System.Type, and (2) create objects of the associate C# type?

By the way, this is a very contrived example to explain the problem I'm trying to solve, don't worry too much about whether Generic makes sense or not!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing you can do is use reflection. This because while the `int` of `Generic<int>` is known at compile-time, the `field.FieldType` is known only at runtime.

Reflection example:

```
Type type = typeof(Generic<>).MakeGenericType(field.FieldType);

// Object of type Generic<field.FieldType>
object gen = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

But even here, from a `Type` (`field.FieldType`) you obtain another `Type` (`type`)

There are normally three ways of using this:

- Full reflection: you use the object of type `Generic<type>` only through reflection. You create it through `Activator.CreateInstance` and from there you begin using `Type.GetMethod()` and `Invoke()`

```
Type type = typeof(Generic<>).MakeGenericType(field.FieldType);

// Object of type Generic<field.FieldType>
object gen = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
MethodInfo isArray = type.GetMethod("IsArray");
bool result = (bool)isArray.Invoke(gen, null);
```

- Interfaces/base classes: you have a non-generic base class or interface that is common between all the `Generic<T>`. You use your object only though that interface/base class.

```
public class Generic<T> : IComparable where T : new()
{
    public bool IsArray()
    {
        return typeof(T).IsArray;
    }

    public T Create()
    {
        return new T();
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

Type type = typeof(Generic<>).MakeGenericType(field.FieldType);
IComparable cmp = (IComparable)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
int res = cmp.CompareTo(cmp);
```

- A generic method where you put all the handling of the `Generic<T>`. That is the only method that is used through reflection.

```
public static void WorkWithT<T>() where T : new()
{
    Generic<T> g = new Generic<T>();
    T obj = g.Create();
    Console.WriteLine(g.IsArray());
}

var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("WorkWithT").MakeGenericMethod(field.FieldType);

// Single reflection use. Inside WorkWithT no reflection is used.
method.Invoke(null, null);
```